# CSS block doesn't show click on a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button which should display the social links buttons "div class=footer-share" on clicking it.

Button code:

```
<div class="footer-share-icon-main icon-footer-share"></div>
```

The block:

```
<ul class="footer-share" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#" class="left-qr" target="_blank"><li class="fa fa-weixin-qr"></li></a>
  <a href="https://fr.pinterest.com/artworkprive/" target="_blank"><li class="footer-share-icon fa fa-pinterest-p"></li></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/artworkprive/" target="_blank"><li class="footer-share-icon fa fa-instagram"></li></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/ArtworkPrive" target="_blank"><li class="footer-share-icon fa fa-twitter"></li></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ArtworkPrive" target="_blank"><li class="footer-share-icon fa fa-facebook"></li></a>
</ul>
```

Using JQuery

```
$('.footer-share-icon-main').click(function () {
    if ($('ul.footer-share').is(':hidden')) {
    //alert('hello');
            $('ul.footer-share').slideDown(300);
    } else if ($('ul.footer-share').is(':visible')) {
    //alert('hello');
            $('ul.footer-share').slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

The button is on the bottom left
[image]
The button works [here](http://artwork-prive.com) but not [here](http://awp.dev-websiting.fr)
Can this issue be resolved by using styles?

Comment: That is not a button, but a link with special font...

Comment: Can you state what browser you are working in? And what "does not work" means? In Firefox, both buttons show a response (being an alert in the second case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, despite the short question:

Check out the `<div class="footer-container">`. It has the property `overflow: hidden` and it says thats coming from `global.css:9800`.

Just remove that style and you are set.

Comment: @tarekfellah Sorry for that. I don't know how helpful this post will be for others, but consider accepting the answer so this can be resolved.